# For-comprehensions over an RDD of Try of List elements

Tags: list, scala, apache-spark, monads, for-comprehension

in a Spark process I have an `RDD[Try[(A, B)]]`. I have to transform this `RDD` using a function `f: B => List[C]`. What I want to obtain is an `RDD[Try[(A, B, C)]`, in which I have to `flatMap` the list obtained from the application of function `f`.

I tryed this:

```
val tryRdd = // Obtain the RDD[Try[(A, B)]]
val transformedRdd = 
  tryRdd.map {
    pair =>
      for {
        (a, b) <- pair
        c <- f(b)
      } yield {
        (a, b, c)
      }
  }
```

Unfortunately what I am obtaining is an `RDD[Try[Nothing]]`. Why? Can anyone help me to understand where I am wrong?

I suppose that problem is not really related to `RDD`. Probabily `RDD` with `List` will end with the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The for-comprehension is translated to

```
pair.flatMap { case (a, b) => f(b).map { case c => (a, b, c) } }
```

But `f(b).map(...)` will give you a `List[(A, B, C)]`, not a `Try[(A, B, C)]` which you want for the argument of `pair.flatMap`. So the code shouldn't compile at all (unless you have a strange implicit conversion in scope).

But if you are using, say, IntelliJ, it can fail to show the error and show an incorrect type (or the other way around, it can show errors in working code): you need to actually build the project to see the real errors.

Comment: Yes, I am using IntelliJ. I will try to build my code and I will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to formally type your RDD ?

```
val transformedRdd : RDD[Try[Tuple3]] = ...
```

Edit :
If this does raise you an error, then the output of the map is wrong.
The `pair` variable's type is Try. 
Since scala doesn't do it for you, you must add some instruction to interact with its content (the tuple (A,B)).
Plus, you don't have to keep the Try type.
I would use a flatMap to keep successes and clean my RDD.
Something like

```
val transformedRdd = tryRdd.flatMap {value =>
  value match {
    case Success((a,b)) => ...
  }
}
```

Watch http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.3/scala/util/Try.html for more informations about the Try class.

Comment: Yes, and the error is the following: _Expression of type RDD[Try[Nothing]] doesn't conform to expected type RDD[Try(A, B, C)]_